# WooCommerce Mini Cart is flickering when close to it?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi Stack i have one little problem with weird flickering on header cart widget in my [WooCommerce site](https://frags2fishes.com/) when product is [added to cart](https://frags2fishes.com/product/lrs-reef-frenzy-8oz-pack/). The problem is when i close to it, it show and dissapear fast, so customer cant see what is showing into dropdown widget. I thtink that this is JS issue on that how is called functions `OpenNav()` and `CloseNav()`. This is entire CSS for that block:

```
<div class="cart-widget tooltip">
<span class="tooltiptext"></span><div onmouseover="openNav()" 
onmouseout="closeNav()">
 <a class="cart-contents" href="https://siteurl.com/cart/"><i class="fa 
fa-shopping-cart"></i><div class="cart-crl">1</div></a>
</div><div onmouseover="openNav()" onmouseout="closeNav()" id="mySidenav" 
class="sidenav" style="display: none;"><div id="accordion" 
class="woocommerce">  <div class="sidebar-quickcart">
```

AND CSS:

```
#accordion ul ul {
 margin:0 20px;
}
#accordion li {
padding: 0;
margin:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
 #accordion{
 padding:20px;
max-height: 550px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
#accordion::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
background-color: #F5F5F5;
 }

.sidenav{
-webkit-animation: fadeIn .8s; 
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; 
 animation: fadeIn .8s;
 animation-fill-mode: both;
 }
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
        0% {opacity: 0;}
        100% {opacity: 1;}
     }

     @keyframes fadeIn {
        0% {opacity: 0;}
        100% {opacity: 1;}
     }
#mySidenav a.checkout{
float:right;
}
.woocommerce #mySidenav ul.cart_list li img, .woocommerce .widget 
ul.cart_list li img{
float: left;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 10px;
width: 50px;
height: auto;
box-shadow: none;
}
```

This is **OpenNav()** and **Closenav() function**s:

```
function openNav(){
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "block";
}
function closeNav(){
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "none";
}
var $crtscroll = jQuery('#mySidenav');
jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
$crtscroll.css({display:"none"});
});
```

Can someone to help me to stop this flickering, and to be like [theme demo site](https://themehunk.com/wp-themes/shopline-pro/)?

Comment: Close to it as in the mouse cursor? Is it opening and closing the nav, as you have  ``mouseover`` and ``mouseout`` events for opening and closing the nav that could be causing the issue. Please include your CSS as well.

Comment: Yes when close with mouse cursor to it.. Will include now.

Comment: Please also include the ``openNav()`` and ``closeNav()`` functions as well, as it seems those are likely the cause.

Comment: Your CSS is still incomplete. We're missing most of the referenced elements such as ``sidenav`` and ``sidebar-quickcart``, and the most important would be the element your JS is applying styles to which is ``mySidenav``.

Comment: Added functions too.. I ant undestand why not works like on original demo site: https://themehunk.com/wp-themes/shopline-pro/

Comment: Added CSS classes you requested too..

Comment: As I play around with it comparing to the original, nothing seems inherently out of place to me, but something must be overlapping triggering a mouseleave event. I've removed the tooltip and even left only the cart in the ``header-extra`` but its still occurring. Hopefully someone a little more familiar with jquery can find the irregularity.